# Positive and negative sides of YAML and PROPERTIES config formats

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul, consul-kv

I'm working on spring cloud app and can not decide which way of storing config in consul kv would be better: whole YAML or single parameters? What positive and negative sides has each way?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to store the complete file in Consul to make portability easier, in case you want to move from Consul to something else in the future.
AFAIK, other than that there are no up- or downsides to it really.